# When creating a maven module project, how to set language to scala?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I have intellij 11 ultimate.

When creating a new maven module project, how do I set the project to use scala as the default language?

Is there a way to run multiple versions of scala in intellij?  (not at the same time, but for different projects).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can create a normal java project and then go to `project structure -> modules-> facets` and add the scala facet if you have the scala plugin installed.

The version of scala your project will use depends on the scala runtime selected in the facet, so yes it's possible to have different scala versions in different projects.

Answer (score 0):

When importing a Maven project into IntelliJ, as long as you have installed the Scala plugin for IntelliJ, I think it should recognise the project as Scala and add the Scala Facet to the Module.

Here is an example https://github.com/adamretter/Skullfuck/blob/master/pom.xml of a simple Maven POM that I use that includes the better of the two Maven Scala Plugins. If you also install Zinc, you can have Maven use the Zinc compiler to speed up Scala compilation.

If IntelliJ does not recognise the Scala'ness of the imported Maven project, simply go to 'Module Settings' by right-clicking on the project, go to 'Facets' and then click the '+' and add the Scala facet. If it complains about not finding the compiler you should be able to select it from the down as it is a dependency of the Maven project anyway.